# Ubuntu 18.04 completely freezes after waking from suspend to memory

Tags: 18.04, hp

I suspect I'm having the same problem on the same laptop (HP Probook 4540s with after market SSD) than the user posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092080/ubuntu-18-04-freezes-after-resuming-from-suspend/1127302) and I'm really battling to find the solution. 
After suspending to memory and waking again, the laptop hangs completely withing 2 - 10s.  When it hangs I'm not even able to open the console using ctrl alt F2. Only solution is to hold down the power button.

My kernel version is "Linux version 4.18.0-16-generic" and all app are updated as of 2019/03/20.

What I have tired so var:

```
rmmod hp_accel hp_wmi hp_wireless
```

Did this just before suspending in the hope that it might be one of the HP drivers as this seems to be specific to HP. No luck.

Had the failure, hard reboot and then have a look at journal, but there is nothing from after we went to sleep.

Ran the following command:

```
echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state; journalctl -f
```

This is handy as the sleep does not lock the device requiring login again, giving you some time to try an figure out whats happening. Problem is that journal does not spit anything out (once had a few lines pop out, not hanging for about 10s but nothing from journal from after suspend).

The above two tests points me to an issue in journal, but I've not been able to disable journal to test this.

Any think I can try and test?  Problem is VERY reproducible.

Graphics card is a Intel® Sandybridge Mobile and I have been having this issue even from a fresh install.

**EDIT**

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.2G        1.3G        231M        1.3G        2.1G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="e29950d0-4e71-45fd-8081-ce907359e16c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e0cefbf7-4e11-437c-909e-a1a3acbfa1a8"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="5CAB-AE29" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="f51590a1-535e-4ce2-86cb-b2b61589962c"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
```

cat /etc/fstab

```
UUID=e29950d0-4e71-45fd-8081-ce907359e16c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5CAB-AE29  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
I have the dir but not the file...

grep -i resume /etc/default/grub
Returns nothing...

**EDIT 2**

Results from lsblk -a

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6405
loop1    7:1    0  91.1M  1 loop /snap/core/6531
loop2    7:2    0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop3    7:3    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/206
loop4    7:4    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop5    7:5    0 271.7M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/117
loop6    7:6    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop7    7:7    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop8    7:8    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop9    7:9    0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/352
loop10   7:10   0  34.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop11   7:11   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop12   7:12   0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350
loop13   7:13   0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/782
loop14   7:14   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
loop15   7:15   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
loop16   7:16   0 143.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
loop17   7:17   0  35.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop18   7:18   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop19   7:19   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/57
loop20   7:20   0         0 loop 
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 465.3G  0 part /
```

**EDIT 3**

Removed all the snap apps that I could install with apt and now I only have the following:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350
loop1    7:1    0  91.1M  1 loop /snap/core/6531
loop2    7:2    0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/782
loop3    7:3    0  35.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop4    7:4    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6405
loop5    7:5    0 143.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
loop6    7:6    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop7    7:7    0         0 loop 
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 465.3G  0 part /
```

Also increased the swap file to 6GB

Comment: Did you check your RAM (e.g. using MemTest)? I've experienced similar issues with bad RAM modules. Is your firmware up to date?

Comment: Edit your question (not into the comments please) to include the output of `free -h` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `grep -i resume /etc/default/grub`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema, I've added the info you requested.

Comment: @danzel.  If you are referring to bios firmware, then yes, updated a few weeks ago (before installing ubuntu 18.04) and I ran its mem test this morning with a pass.  Do you have another mem test that you prefer I run?

Comment: @ChristoLabuschagne How do you "suspend to memory"? Has this always been a problem, or something new that just started?

Comment: @heynnema, usually by closing the lid or if running on battery and no activity for a while.  I have the same problem when running "sudo echo mem /sys/power/state;" to try and stimulate the problem.  I had Ubuntu 16.04 on the laptop, not having this when waking from sleep but random freezes while using the device, thought it was the HDD giving issues and wanted to upgrade anyway so added an SSD and a fresh install of 18.04.02 and I've been having this issue since then.

Comment: @ChristoLabuschagne just to confirm... the "sudo echo mem..." does suspend, or hibernate? The system freezes were on 16.04... are they still there in 18.04? Which problem started AFTER you installed 18.04? Do you have a lot of snaps installed? snap list.

Comment: @heynnema.  Had random freezes on 16.04 which might be related but no way to be sure.  They never happened directly after suspend.  Replace the HDD with an SSD and installed 18.04.02 and had this issue from the first day of using 18.04.  From what I understand "sudo echo **disk**" will hibernate.  It does seem like it sleeps as pressing the power button wakes instantly and the power button led flashes indicating sleep.  I haven't installed anything via snap. Basically have eclipse and pycharm on there.

Comment: If you're hibernating, then your /swapfile isn't large enough. I asked about snaps, because your blkid showed so many loop devices. See if lsblk gives more of a clue as to what they are. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Updated the post with the results as requested.

Comment: @ChristoLabuschagne yes, as I thought, the lsblk showed us that you have a number of snaps installed. Some are updates or dups. I can't say for sure, but it's possible that one of the snaps might be causing a problem. Investigate if you can replace an existing snap with a non-snap version, and if nothing else, you'll see better boot times. You can also look into changing your /swapfile to 4G and see if that makes any difference. Otherwise, I don't know what else to suggest for you. Keep me posted, ok?

Comment: @heynnema.  Alas, no luck

Comment: @ChristoLabuschagne Thanks for keeping me in the loop. "no luck"... with what? The larger swapfile? Check to make sure you have the latest BIOS for your HP Probook 4540s.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear @heynnema.  Updated the post.  Made swap file bigger and removed most of the snap programs.  Updated to the latest bios a month ago before installing 18.04.

Comment: @heynnema I've had freezing issues, and I checked my swapfile and saw it was only 2G (40G Ram) -- I followed the instructions here: https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/ and now I can suspend. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MathStudent.  Two or so weeks ago I tried your solution and off the bat it did not seem to work, but the problem seems to be gone now.  Not sure if it was an apt update or the swap file, but its GONE!  Thanks if it was your solution, or thanks to whom ever fixed what ever driver!